# USB stick for MAC

Tags: boot

I would like to install Ubuntu on my MAC but I need to have Ubuntu on a memory stick rather than a CD. Is there a  memory stick I can buy

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu offers instructions on how to install it's OS on a MAC using a USB. Follow the instructions on this website: [Click here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick)